# What is the meaning of $1_1$, or $1_2$?

Tags: matrices, statistics, vectors

I came across the following notation, the meaning of which was not explained in the paper itself nor in my usual math bibles, so I'm turning to you. Let me just quote it in its entirety:

> Let $A, \delta$ and $c$  be a $1_1$ by $1_2$ matrix, a $1_2$ component vector, and a $1_1$ component vector, respectively.

--
Liew, C.K., 1976. "A Two-Stage Least-Squares Estimation with Inequality Restrictions on Parameters," The Review of Economics and Statistics, MIT Press, vol. 58(2), pages 234-38, May.

I have no clue whatsoever about what things like $1_1$ actually mean. I am quite firm in the notation of theoretical econometrics (at least I think I'm firm...) but I cannot remember that I came across this notation before. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Cheers, 
Benjamin

Comment: You may have access to the paper here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1924031

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is the **ones vector**, a vector with all entries one. You can read about it [here](http://ee263.stanford.edu/notes/matrix-primer-lect1.pdf). The subscript could further indicate the size of the vector or matrix.

Comment: Zelia,thanks for your input. I too thought it might be the ones vector, but given that $A$ is a matrix, its dimensions should be given as integers, not vectors. Ergo, it cannot be the ones vector...

Comment: $A$ is given as a $1_1$ by $1_2$ matrix, so it can refer to the rows and the columns (1 row and 2 columns).

Comment: But wouldn't that be a highly unusual way of denoting matrix dimensions? Moreover, since $\delta$ are the parameters to be estimated and $c$ are the inequality-constraints, I reasonably doubt, that $A$ is always a 1x2 matrix (which is a vector, anyway...)